# Не применяются стили для WP

Tags: css, wordpress

Через редактор были изменены стили. После сохранения, редактированный css файлик сохранился в измененном виде, т.е. показаны последняя версия кода и в редакторе, и в менеджере файлов на хосте. Однако, стили не применяются. Через дев тул применяются старые стили. Как быть?

Comment: Попробуйте обновить страницу через Ctrl + F5

Comment: **1**. В редакторе ВП ничего не делай. Вообще отключи его нафик  Только правильные блокноты по ФТП **2**. В файле стилей есть/можно указать версию. При её изменении ничего рефрешить не нужно.

Comment: @SeVlad а почему? Я сам редактором wp не пользуюсь, мне интересно, откуда такое мнение.

Comment: @KAGGDesign. Это предостережение для нубов, не знающих правильные методы. Вообще передавать тексты POSTот не оч. надёжно. А если малейшая ошибка в коде (потерялась точка с зп. напр) и всё, сайт умер. Данных  ФТП нет, бекапов нет.. Такие случаи не мои фантазии - это регулярно по форумам вижу.

Comment: @SeVlad ну да, в самом деле - запороть сайт ничего не стоит. Понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проверьте, что файл, который вы изменили подключен и что все стили, которые на сайте используются - действительно берутся из него.
2. Почистите кеш-браузера.
3. Проверьте, что на сайте не используется плагин кеширования W3C Total Cache или другие, в таком случае нужно почистить кеш.
4. Попробуйте открыть сайт в другом браузере.
5. Через инспектор попробуйте открыть файл стилей "Open in New Tab" и проверьте что там есть ваши стили.

Answer (score 1):

Как заметили предыдущие ответчики - это, скорее всего, кеш. Или кеш браузера, или плагина, или внешний кеш, как в моем случае - кеш Cloud Flare.  Ковыряем .htaccess на предмет кеша (ставим, например, меньшее время), временно отключаем кеш или просто его чистим.